# Create Task from Email in Gmail

Tags: gmail, tasks, google-tasks

Is it possible to create a new Google Tasks entry from an email in Gmail?

Use case: create a reminder/task to respond to an email on a certain day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a "More Actions" button above each email with an option to "Add to tasks". This then adds the email to your list of tasks which appears in the bottom right of your screen. Clicking on the small arrow to the right of the task allows you to edit the options and attributes assigned to the task, for example to set a reminder or additional notes about the task.

Answer (score 4):

If you have keyboard shortcuts turned on, just use Shift-T. (You can then use Shift-Enter to get to the task options.)

Comment: Shift+T is a very nice shortcut!